# Jquery div class changes when menu link/links clicked

Tags: jquery

I need the initial box to be visible onload and not just when a menu item is clicked.

HTML:

```
   <div id='nav'>
       <a id="show_apps">Appetizers</a> | <a id="show_soups">Soups and Salads</a> | <a   
        id="show_entrees">Entrees</a>
         </div>

          <div id="menu_container">
         <div id="menu_apps">
        Content of the App Section Here
     </div>
      <div id="menu_soups">
         Content of the Soups Section Here
        </div>
      <div id="menu_entrees">
         Content of the Entrees Section Here
         </div>
         </div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav a").click(function(){
  var id =  $(this).attr('id');
  id = id.split('_');
  $("#menu_container div").hide(); 
  $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).show();
    });
     });
```

CSS:

```
  #menu_container{
    width: 650px;
    height: auto;
  padding-left: 30px;
  }

 #menu_container div{display:none;}
```

If you look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/KUtY5/1/

I'd like to add a transition time when the elements change as well as display the first element on page load. Then when you click on the other elements, they change accordingly.

Any ideas? :(

Comment: please provide html, and working jsfiddle, then we can try to simplify code...

Comment: I've tweaked it. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the first div of the menu container, place this in your document ready handler

```
$("#menu_container div:first-child").show();
```

You can use the fadeIn method instead of the show method to achieve a transition

```
$("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).fadeIn();
```

[Heres a working demo of what you wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/YH5mx/)

Answer (score 0):

You hide them all. You can show the first div when doc is ready.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#nav a").click(function(){
          var id =  $(this).attr('id');
          id = id.split('_');
          $("#menu_container div").hide(); 
          $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).show();
       });

        $('#menu_apps').show();
    });
```

Comment: Aaah you legend!! Thank you!! Any way I can add transition effects to the changing divs?

Comment: That works pretty well! It slides the boxes though. Any fade transition effects possible?

Comment: .fadeIn() / .fadeOut()